# Установка Android SDK

Tags: android, справка

- Какие шаги нужно выполнить, чтобы установить и настроить Android SDK на Window или Linux?
- Какие требования предъявляются к рабочему окружению?

Answer (score 2):

**Настройка установленной IDE**

Если IDE уже установлена, и желательно использовать ее для разработки приложений Android, установка Android SDK потребует загрузить SDK Tools, а затем выбрать дополнительные пакеты из Android SDK для установки (например, платформу Android и образ системы). При использовании существующей версии Eclipse, можно добавить плагин ADT к нему.

Скачайте архив с SDK: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download

**Windows**

Требования

- Windows XP (32-разрядная), Vista (32- или 64-разрядная) или Windows 7 (32- или 64-разрядная версия)
- Eclipse IDE 3.6.2 (Helios) или выше, включая JDT плагин
- JDK 6 (JRE не является достаточным)
- Android Development Tools плагин (рекомендуется)

Установка

Скачанный пакет представляет собой исполняемый файл, который запускает установку. Программа установки проверит машину на наличие необходимых инструментов, таких как надлежащий Java SE Development Kit (JDK) и установит его в случае необходимости. Затем программа установки сохранит Android SDK Tools в папку по умолчанию (или можно указать местоположение).

Дважды щелкните на исполняемый exe-файл, чтобы начать установку. Запишите название и место, в котором он сохраняет SDK в на системе, чтобы при необходимости обратиться к каталогу SDK позже, при установке плагина ADT и при использовании инструментов SDK из командной строки.

После завершения установки, установщик предлагает начать работу с менеджером Android SDK. Если будет использоваться Eclipse, не надо запускать менеджер Android SDK, вместо этого - перейти к установке плагина Eclipse. Если используется другая IDE, запустить диспетчер SDK и добавлять платформы и пакеты.

**Linux**

Распакуйте скачанный .tgz файл. По умолчанию SDK распакует файлы в папку с именем Android-SDK-linux_x86. Переместите его в нужное место на компьютере, например, папку "tools" в домашнем каталоге.

Запишите имя и местоположение каталога SDK в вашей системе, чтобы при необходимости обратиться к каталогу SDK позже, при создании плагина ADT и при использовании инструментов SDK из командной строки.

Если используется Eclipse, перейти к установке плагина Eclipse. В противном случае, если используется другая IDE, читать про добавление платформ и пакетов.

Поиск и устранение неисправностей Ubuntu

Если нужна помощь в установке и настройке Java на компьютере, эти ресурсы могут быть полезными:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/JavaInstallation

Шаги для установки Java и Eclipse, до установки Android SDK и ADT Plugin.

Если установлена 64-разрядная система на компьютере, необходимо установить ia32-библиотеки пакета с помощью apt-get:

```
apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Далее установить Java:

```
apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Менеджер пакетов Ubuntu в настоящее время (на момент написания перевода справки) не предлагает версии Eclipse 3.6 для скачивания, поэтому рекомендуется скачать Eclipse с сайта http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. Java или RCP  версия Eclipse рекомендуется.

---

[Setting Up an Existing IDE](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html).

*Portions of this page are modifications based on work created and shared by the Android Open Source Project and used according to terms described in the Creative Commons 2.5 Attribution License.*